# when selecting elements, why using id, class and tag like ".my-class", "button" is faster than those like "[name='my-name']"

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

when selecting elements, for example, `<a class='my-class' name='my-name'>sth</a>`, why using something like `.my-class`, `a` is faster than those like `[name='my-name']`. In my opinion, selector traverse dom tree using depth first search(please correct me if I misunderstand), why the former faster?

Comment: In a modern browser, it probably doesn't make much real difference.

Comment: @Pointy It might be realted to css psecifity ?

Comment: true but suppose you dont want to select all `a` elements. what would you do then?

Comment: @RoyiNamir well that's a good point, but I think attribute references count the same as class references for specificity.

Comment: if all ```a``` elements are with same attributes ```<a class='my-class' name='my-name'>sth</a>```, it should be same performance in theory using the 3 ways, right?

Comment: once dom tree built, "id", "class", "tagname" willed be added to index, right? does anybody know some thing about browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that `id`, `class` are added into index which results in faster searching.